# python Ctype : problem with callback in making python custom library

Tags: python, callback, ctypes

The whole scenario is like this:

- there is a function setmessagelistener(a_structure,function_pointer) in my c library.
- i am writing a **python library** which is a wrapper on above mentioned c library using **Ctypes**.
  so what i did is something like this:

  ```
  def setlistener(a_structure,function_pointer)

   listenerDeclaration = CFUNCTYPE(c_void_p, c_void_p)

   listenerFunction = listenerDeclaration(function_pointer)

   setMsgListener = c_lib.setMessageListener

   setMsgListener.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_void_p]

   setMsgListener.restype = c_ubyte

   if (setMsgListener(a_structure, listenerFunction)==0):

      sys.exit("Error setting message listener.")
  ```
- Now,another python program uses above function from my python library to do the work,but the problem is:

when i run the program it gives me segmentation fault because the local object( listenerfunction) is already garbage collected(i think so) when control returned from the library function setListener() as it being a local object.

is there any workaround/solution to this problem?or am i missing something?
please suggest...
thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

As you suspect, you need to keep a reference to listenerFunction as long as it is needed.  Perhaps wrap the function in a class, create an instance and set the listenerFunction as a member variable.

See the Python documentation for ctypes [callbacks](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html?highlight=ctypes#callback-functions), especially the important note at the end of the section.